# how to use md5() function with my sql database

Tags: php, sql, md5

my problem is solved. I don't expect for more answers. So, please don't vote down, cause I need some reputations to vote up for others post. Thanks

I try to use `md5()` for the login system but it doesn't encrypt password. It still display the original password on my database. Here is my code:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=md5($_POST['mypassword']); 



$sql="select * from $tbl_name where username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
header("location:login.html");
}
?>
```

I just edit my code to `$mypassword=md5($_POST['mypassword']);`

Comment: echo md5($mypassword); should be $mypassword = md5($mypassword);

Comment: SQL Ijnection like a hell... Oh no! Seriously?!

Comment: You should keep in mind that MD5 is considered insecure nowadays. If you start something new, you should use a more secure hashing algorithm, like SHA1.

Comment: Also, `mysql_*` functions shouldn't be used anymore since they are going to be deprecated in future versions of PHP.

Comment: +1, Instead use Mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider SHA1 is almost as weak as MD5. The get collision resistance, use SHA2 or SHA3.

Comment: No plain hash function is appropriate for password hashing. This includes SHA-1/2/3. You must use a salt and key strengthening. bcrypt is a good choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You just printed the md5d password, store it into the variable before insertion**

```
$mypassword = md5($_POST['mypassword']);
$sql="select * from $tbl_name where username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

I think your logic have some problem, are you storing passwords in encrypted form? then only you can fetch the data by this select command, otherwise the `$count=mysql_num_rows($result);` is zero always

and please take a look here also

**[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)**

Comment: Sorry,I new to php. I don't understand how the md5() work. Do I need to store password in encypted form in database OR I it will auto encrypt when I use md5() ?

Comment: no it will not auto encrypt, you must encrypt the password using the function `md5()`  and use that encrypted value for storing inside the table, just like above.

`$mypassword = md5($_POST['mypassword']);`
`$sql="insert into $tbl_name (username,password) values ('$myusername','$mypassword');`
`$result=mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: what doesnt work?!!!!
Do you look into your table? what you can see in password column?

Comment: ah now it encypt but I can't login with the form? what should I do?

Comment: Sorry my internet connection is slow, now everything work well. thank you very much. Sorry but I don't have enough reputation to vote up you...Thanks again.

Comment: @LoverOfEvening Both tutorials advocate really bad practices. Please don't advertise them.

Comment: Please, *please* escape your POST variables to protect against SQL injection. Every time you don't escape them, a kitten dies.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MD5('testing');
```

For example

```
$sql="select * from $tbl_name where username='$myusername' and password=MD5($mypassword)";
```

In your sql

Answer (score 3):

Storing unsalted MD5 hashes of passwords, is almost the same as storing them plaintext. With off-the-shelf hardware, one can try 8 Giga passwords per second, that means you can brute-force a whole dictionary with about 500'000 words in less than a millisecond!

Even more, there are tons of precalculated hash-tables for MD5 without salt, so just take an MD5 hash of your own password, type it into google and see what the original password was, or maybe it's better not to do it...

That's why one should use a slow key-derivation function like **BCrypt** nowadays. PHP 5.5 will have it's own functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` ready, to simplify this task. There is a [compatibility pack](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash) for PHP 5.3/5.4 available, downloadable at [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

I would invite you to ready more about correctly hashing passwords in this [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Comment: Just to emphasize: Hashing passwords with plain SHA-1/2/3 is almost as bad as using MD5. Those new password hashing functions are great, use them!

Answer (score 1):

now you just echoing encrypted password to output:

```
echo md5($mypassword);
```

what you want is assign to the `$mypassword`

```
$mypassword = md5($mypassword);
```

Comment: what doesnt work? print $mypassword and you will see the result

Answer (score 1):

You MUST escape your strings, to block SQL injections. At the very least use `mysql_real_escape_string()`. And don't use MD5, use Sha1:

```
$mypassword = sha1($_POST['mypassword']);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']);
$sql="select * from $tbl_name where username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Your use of SHA1 is just as bad as MD5. Both are cheap to brute-force, use bcrypt instead.

Comment: I agree, but it's even easier to attack a database by SQL injection, so that was the main point of my post. Given that the user didn't understand what `md5()` did, I think perhaps suggesting `sha1()` was a step too far! However, for a one-liner it adds slightly better encryption than MD5.

Comment: Both MD5 and SHA1 have significant collision weaknesses(irrelevant for password hashing), but first pre-images(relevant for password hashing) require >2^120 work, even for MD5. So guessing passwords is *much* more efficient than exploiting the weaknesses of MD5. The practical difference in strength for SHA-1 and MD5 for password hashing is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you to use `mysqli` or `PDO`.You just printed the md5d password, you need to store it value to particular variable and use that variable in to your query.To do it  try this

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect"); 

mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$newpassword = md5($mypassword);

$sql="select * from $tbl_name where username='".$myusername."' and password='".$mypassword."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword"); 
    header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
    header("location:login.html");
}
?>
```